# Simplify high-order Bezier curve

Tags: bezier

I have an array of control points that represent a Bezier curve. It could be a fifth-order or 100-order Bezier curve, or anything in-between. I am looking for a way to simplify that Bezier curve into multiple cubic Bezier curves. An illustration below shows how tenth-degree curve can be simplified to three-degree curve, but I want to go further and simplify it to several cubic Bezier curves to achieve better approximation.

[image: http://snag.gy/aHPjc.jpg]

Code example would be very helpful.

Comment: In general : a segmented bezier curve is nothing else than a b-spline curve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mohsenmadi already pointed out: in general this is not a thing you can do without coming up with your own error metric. Another idea is to go "well let's just approximate this curve as a *sequence* of lower order curves", so that we get something that looks better, and doesn't really require error metrics. This is a bit like "flattening" the curve to lines, except instead of lines we're going to use cubic Bezier segments instead, which gives nice looking curves, while keeping everything "tractable" as far as modern graphics libraries are concerned.

Then what we can do is: split up that "100th order curve" into a sequence of cubic Beziers by sampling the curve at regular intervals and then running those points through a Catmull-Rom algorithm. The procedure's pretty simple:

1. Pick some regularly spaced values for `t`, like 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8 and 1, then
2. create the set of points tvalues.map(t => getCoordinate(curve, t)). Then,
3. build a virtual start and end point: forming a point `0` by starting at point `1` and moving back along its tangent, and forminga point `n+1` by starting at `n` and following its tangent. We do this, because:
4. build the poly-Catmull-Rom, starting at virtual point `0` and ending at virtual point `n+1`.

Let's do this in pictures. Let's start with an 11th order Bezier curve:

[image]

And then let's just sample that at regular intervals:

[image]

We invent a 0th and n+1st point:

[image]

And then we run the Catmull-Rom procedure:

```
i = 0
e = points.length-4
curves = []
do {
  crset = points.subset(i, 4)
  curves.push(formCRCurve(crset))
} while(i++<e)
```

What does formCRCurve do? Good question:

```
formCRCurve(points: p1, p2, p3, p4):
  d_start = vector(p2.x - p1.x, p2.y - p1.y)
  d_end = vector(p4.x - p3.x, p4.y - p3.y)
  return Curve(p2, d_start, d_end, p3)
```

So we see why we need those virtual points: given four points, we can form a Catmull-Rom curve from points 2 to point 3, using the tangent information we get with a little help from points 1 and 4.

Of course, we actualy want Bezier curves, not Catmull-Rom curves, but because they're the same "kind" of curve, we can [freely convert between the two](http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#catmullconv), so:

```
i = 0
e = points.length-4
bcurves = []
do {
  pointset = points.subset(i, 4)
  bcurves.push(formBezierCurve(pointset))
} while(i++<e)

formBezierCurve(points: p1, p2, p3, p4):
  return bezier(
    p2,
    p2 + (p3 - p1)/6
    p3 - (p4 - p2)/6
    p3
  )
```

So a Catmull-Rom curve based on points {p1,p2,p3,p4}, which passes *through* points `p2` and `p3`, can be written as an equivalent Bezier curve that uses the start/control1/control2/end coodinates `p2`, `p2 + (p3 - p1)/6`, `p3 - (p4 - p2)/6`, and `p3`.

Comment: Two questions: **(1)** What are `d_start` and `d_end` doing in that second `formCurve` function? And should the second function replace the first, or should I use them both somehow? **(2)** I tried implementing this, using only your last paragraph for information, but only got reasonable results when I used `p2 + (p3 - p1)/6` and `p3 - (p4 - p2)/6`. Note that I switched the `+` and `-`. Did I make a mistake or did you?

Comment: gah, good points! let me update the answer. The second function replaces the first (the first yields a Catmull-Rom curve, the second a Bezier curve, based on the Catmull-Rom curve). And yes, I totally accidentally'd the +/- signs.

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to know that there are no approximating lower degree curves that would do you justice! You are bound to introduce errors no escape. The questions then is: how to approximate such that the original and resultant curves are visually similar?

Assume your original curve is of degree *n*. First, [subdivide](http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/Bezier/bezier-sub.html) it. You can subdivide a curve as many times as you want without introducing any errors. Here, the degree of each subdivisions is still *n*, but the geometric complexity and rate of curvature are reduced considerably. Second, you [reduce the degree](http://www.sirver.net/blog/2011/08/23/degree-reduction-of-bezier-curves/) of each subdivision which is by now a simple shape with no high curvature that would introduce approximation errors.